# Dashboard to show content from multiple SPS List

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, dashboard

My query is more of advisory to understand if the solution I`m planning to opt is that right.

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Working on building Dashboard in SharePoint 2013 to show data from multiple SharePoint lists.

Solution Option -

use CEWP with XSL using content types.

Please validate

Comment: @monica kindly share your views

Comment: Firstly, you can display data from multiple lists without using XSL at all. You jsut need to add a webpart for each list on your dashboard page.
Secondly, presuming the dashboard will display multiple list view webparts, then yes, you can use XSL to change the design of your list views / webparts. I however recommend look at modifying the  client-side rendering (CSR) of the list view webparts using JavaScript. It is much more flexible and better than XSL, in my opinion.

Comment: @mihail can you share some more insight may be any relevant article

Comment: I understand a) Adding list view webpart for each list on my dashboard page. b) confused how will I show data from multiple lists , what webpart am I using here.

Comment: Adding a list view webpart for each list on your dashboard page **=>** Display data from multiple lists on your dashboard page.

Comment: I cannot really give a solution since I don't know how you want to display your lists' data on the dashboard. Here is however a link that can get you started with modifying a list view using JavaScript (instead of XSL): https://content.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2015/5/19/dashboards-and-kpis-made-easy-with-client-side-rendering-(csr)-in-sharepoint-listviews